# How can I use Parallel Stream in this for loop

Tags: java, java-stream

jsonarray object is containing 50000 jsonObject. I need to process this jsonObject to make an object then I want to add this object to a List. It's taking lot of time so I want to use parallel stream to make the object and to add to the list faster.

Here is the code which I want to replace with parallel loop

```
        // I want to insert object in this array
        List<Curriculum> curriculamList = new ArrayList<>();

        // This is the org.json array
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);

        // This loop I want to replace
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            // Start of processing
            Program program = programDAO.getProgramDetails(jsonobject.getInt("programId"));
            Batch batch = batchDAO.getBatchDetails(jsonobject.getInt("batchId"), program);
            if(batch.getBatchId() == 0)
                continue;
            Major major = majorDAO.getMajorDetails(jsonobject.getInt("majorId"));
            Course course = courseDAO.getCourseDetails(jsonobject.getString("courseCode"));
            if(course == null)
                continue;
            double credits = jsonobject.getDouble("credits");
            CourseType courseType = courseTypeDAO.getCourseTypeDetails(program, jsonobject.optString("type"));
            int semesterCount = jsonobject.getInt("semester");
            String prereqCourseString = jsonobject.getString("prereq");
            Course alternateCourse = courseDAO.getCourseDetails(jsonobject.getString("alternate"));

            List<Course> prereqCourseList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (prereqCourseString.length() != 0) {
                String[] prereqCourseSplit = prereqCourseString.split("AND");
                for (String prereqCourseSplitString : prereqCourseSplit) {
                    prereqCourseList.add(courseDAO.getCourseDetails(prereqCourseSplitString.trim()));
                }
            }
            List<Course> prereqChainCourseList = new ArrayList<>();
            // End of processing

            // This is the object
            Curriculum curriculum = new Curriculum(course, credits, courseType, semesterCount, prereqCourseList, prereqChainCourseList, alternateCourse, batch, major);

            // Pushing object into the list
            curriculamList.add(curriculum);
        }
```

Here I tried some code but may be I am in wrong path. How can I use list inside the stream and get the index number of the loop. Please help how can I convert it to Stream.

```
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);
        Stream.of(jsonarray)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(objects -> {
                    // How I can get index number here and push it to the list?
                    JSONObject jsonobject = objects.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Here is the processing code

                    Curriculum curriculum = new Curriculum(course, credits, courseType, semesterCount, prereqCourseList, prereqChainCourseList, alternateCourse, batch, major);

                    // Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final? How to add then?
                    curriculamList.add(curriculum);
                });
```

I am new in java please forgive me if I made any mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream.of(jsonarray)` returns a Stream with a single element, the JSONArray object, which is not what you want.

I think this is what you're going for:

```
List<Curriculum> curriculumList = IntStream.range(0, jsonarray.length()).parallel()
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                // fetch the various parts...

                return new Curriculum(course, credits, courseType, semesterCount, prereqCourseList, prereqChainCourseList, alternateCourse, batch, major);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, it looks like your code is making several blocking network calls. It is often inadvisable to use parallel streams for executing blocking network calls in parallel, as parallel streams are intended for CPU parallelization, so use a single shared threadpool which has only a small number of threads. Therefore you might prefer something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

// start many calls running in parallel
List<Future<Curriculum>> futures = IntStream.range(0, jsonarray.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> executor.submit(() -> {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                // fetch the various parts...

                return new Curriculum(course, credits, courseType, semesterCount, prereqCourseList, prereqChainCourseList, alternateCourse, batch, major);
            })).collect(Collectors.toList());

executor.shutdown();

List<Curriculum> curriculumList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Future<Curriculum> future : futures) {
    curriculumList.add(future.get());
}
```